# If I'm using a For Loop, how can I include the list item as part of the results?

Tags: python, list, api, for-loop, python-requests

I apologize in advance for misused terminology and description, but I'm able to describe it well enough:

I'm making requests to an API, while using a 'for loop' to iterate through a list of subdirectories I've identified for a domain.

```
responses = list() ##defining that responses is a list
responses.clear() ##clearing the list each time I run the script

ids = ['XXXXXXid1XXXXXX', 'XXXXXXid2XXXXXX', 'XXXXXXid3XXXXXX']  ##defining list of ids

for id in ids:
    url = 'https://api.website/PartOfWebsite/{}'.format(id)
    rr = requests.get(url, params= {'apikey': 'my-api-key'})
    data = json.loads(rr.text)
    responses.append(data)
```

When looking at 'responses' after this succesffully runs, the results look like:

```
[{'python_rules': [{'ad': 'some result',
    'ret': 23908092093094808203,
    'shure': 2.5},
   {'ad': 'some result',
    'ret': 902830894023342,
    'share': 2.32},
   {'ad': 'some result',
    'ret': 98209283049820,
    'shure': 21.3}]
```

I would like the results to include the id that is associated to the search, in the 'ids' list. So, the results would look like:

```
[{'python_rules': [{'ad': 'some result',
    'ret': 23908092093094808203,
    'shure': 2.5,
    'id': XXXXXXid1XXXXXX},
   {'ad': 'some result',
    'ret': 902830894023342,
    'share': 2.32
    'id': XXXXXXid2XXXXXX},
   {'ad': 'some result',
    'ret': 98209283049820,
    'shure': 21.3
    'id': XXXXXXid3XXXXXX}]
```

Please let me know if I need to be more specific about what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Just add `data['id'] = id` between `data = json.loads(rr.text)` and `responses.append(data)`

Comment: @Nick https://tenor.com/uhNc.gif

Comment: I'll have to bookmark that one... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the id manually to the resulting `data` dictionary:

```py
responses = list() ##defining that responses is a list
responses.clear() ##clearing the list each time I run the script

ids = ['XXXXXXid1XXXXXX', 'XXXXXXid2XXXXXX', 'XXXXXXid3XXXXXX']  ##defining list of ids

for id in ids:
    url = 'https://api.website/PartOfWebsite/{}'.format(id)
    rr = requests.get(url, params= {'apikey': 'my-api-key'})
    data = json.loads(rr.text)

    data['id'] = id    # <-- add id manually

    responses.append(data)
```